Parcel-bundler: Help fix "No entries found"
Hellow everyone i have a problem, i can't use parcel-bundler because i have this eror "No entries found".
I write npx parcel folder/index.html and i have eror.
No entries found
at Bundler.bundle (my src) 
at async Bundler.serve (my src) 
at async Command.bundle (my src)
Help guys, thanks all!
I try write:
npx parcel index.html npx parcel My Folder/index.html npx parcel ./index.html npx parcel folder vs/My folder/index.html
And i reinstall parcel-bundler..
Result after this  = 0
Thanks guys for help!
